# Adding new pages to MVC 3 project results in "Resource not found" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an existing MVC 3 project I've been working on for a while. Today I decided to add a new page. I added a new view, hooked it up with an actionresult on an existing controller but no dice. I get a 404. I thought maybe something was wonky with the view so I did a response.write in the controller (to take the view out of the equation). No dice. I tried creating a new controller. Same thing. I tried moving an existing page. Same thing. All existing pages work, but I can't add new ones or move existing ones. My keyboard is covered in hair. Please help.

My global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        ); 
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

The view I'm trying to add is /Views/Restaurants/Nearby.

The controller is /Controllers/RestaurantsController and the ActionResult is:

```
public ActionResult Nearby()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: what URL are you using to access the page?

Comment: How have you solved the problem? I have the same issue, added new Action(also a view) to Home controller and newly created page do not work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Start by removing the following useless line from your route definitions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

so that you only have the default route setup:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now in order to access your new controller action you would navigate to `/Restaurants/Nearby`. This will render the `Nearby` action on the `Restaurants` controller:

```
public class RestaurantsController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Nearby()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

which obviously would execute the `~/Views/Restaurants/Nearby.cshtml` view.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but that doesn't work. This url: http://localhost:36472/Restaurants/Nearby returns a 404.

Comment: @dhyasama, start a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the default wizard. Add a `RestaurantsController` exactly as shown in my answer in `~/Controllers/RestaurantsController.cs`. Then add a corresponding `~/Views/Restaurants/Nearby.cshtml` view. Hit F5 to run your project and navigate to `/Restaurants/Nearby`.

Comment: That works. Any idea what could be causing the issue in the original project? I'd rather not copy the entire project over to a new project. Plus, I'd like to gain a deeper understanding rather than just moving along. Thanks again.

Comment: @dhyasama, no idea. I am not familiar with your existing project, nor what it contains. You have shown only a very small portion of it and I have shown you how to make it work. Now if it still doesn't work there might be something else going on on some other part of your code which unfortunately I cannot guess.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I have found many many 'Resource Not Found' solutions which  did not help me. After some time I worked out my issue. Hopefully it will help someone else.

The problem was that I had been messing about with deploying my application, so my project happened to be set to a 'Release' configuration. I had also altered the release configuration to compile to a different folder.

So I think when I was hitting 'Run' in the toolbar, it was picking up an older DLL and running from that.

I only spent three hours on this so I'm happy.

Comment: not exactly my issue but it pointed me to the right direction and saved my time. Actually my main Project was not compiling at all because I somehow unchecked the Build checkbox in Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the Route Debugger NuGet package IIRC,

`Get-Package routedebugger`

If needed, change your web.config entry to activate the route debugger for all requests:

`<add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="true" />`

Then you should build and run your project, and navigate to `/Restaurants/Nearby/`. The resulting diagnostics should tell you where your routing issue (if any) lies. If you are still having trouble, edit your post with the route debugging info and we'll see what we can do!